# Session-and user information

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using codeigniter's session class, what is the equivalent function/properties of $_SESSION['username'] in which username is a database column name ? – 
Also, when I direct log in user to another page how can I retain his state in session ? In native php session, I just issue "session_start(), then choose the column name to put in $_SESSION[columnNAME]", it automatically works then.

I store userinformation after getting it from DB as

```
$this->session->set_userdata("db_result",$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If sessions are enabled in codeigniter then they will autostart you don't need to tell them to start.

Everything else you ask is explained in the codeigniter documentation

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Indeed. By default though, `sess_use_database` is set to false. enable this to true in config/config.php if you would like to save session data to the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider implementing `session_start()` in your [`hooks`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), so that it starts automatically. Probably this is what you need. You can check how to implement hooks in Codeigniter's Documentation.

I don't prefer using codeigniter's session. If you do not use the DB option for session, codeigniter saves it in `$_COOKIE` and all the information we save in the session is clear text.

Its a security risk, because any user and simply read those cookies and install it on his own browser, and the site will start to treat user as authenticated.

So I advice, you stick to traditional PHP Session handling, and as already said, execute `session_start()` in your [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html)

(PS: session being saved in cookies was true as of Codeigniter v1.7.3, I don't know about the latest development.)